# Deduct Qty On Hand from Product Object when an Opportunity is Closed Won

Tags: trigger, opportunity

Need help, I'm trying to figure out how can I make a trigger to update Quantity On Hand in the Product Object when an Opportunity is Closed Won.

- OpportunityLineItems -> Quantity (Standard Field) (Number)
- Product2 -> QtyOnHand (Custom Field) (Number)
- ( Product2.QtyOnHand__c - OpportunityLineItems.Quantity ) = Product2.QtyOnHand__c

Opportunity Stage Updated to Closed Won, then run trigger.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Is what you tried not working?

Comment: I already tried to use Workflows and Formula Fields and didn't works

Comment: So you haven't made a first stab at the code yet at all?

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh Correct!

Comment: It seems like your Qty On Hand is going to be only approximately correct, and will be less accurate over time unless corrected somehow. Are you planning to periodically update this field based on some inventory information?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's wise to rely on the state of a field prior to the start of a transaction as an accurate count. Instead, you should just use a trigger on Opportunity and an aggregate query on the OpportunityLineItem object, which looks up to both Product2 and Opp.

First collect all of your Product2 Ids from the trigger set:

```
Set<id> productIdsToQuery = new Set<id>();
List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems = [SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN : Trigger.New];
for (OpportunityLineItem oli : lineItems) {
    productIdsToQuery.add(oli.Product2Id);
}
```

Next, do an aggregate query on the Closed Won opps related to that Product:

```
List<Account>AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Quantity) totalQuantity, Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2Id IN :productIdsToQuery AND StageName = 'Closed Won' GROUP BY Product2Id];

List<Product2> productsToUpdate = new List<Product2>();    

for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
    Product2 updatedProduct = new Product2(
        id = ar.get('Product2Id');
        QuantityConsumed__c = ar.get('totalQuantity');
    );
    productsToUpdate.add(updatedProduct);       
}

update productsToUpdate;
```

EDIT: You edited your post in the middle of my answer to change what Quantity On Hand means. You need a field for how many you have and then how many have been used (the calculation I listed) and a formula to do the subtraction for 'On Hand'

Comment: Your solution actually only counts how many have been included in an Opportunity. The question is to deduct based on newly closed opportunities.

Comment: My solution counts the sum of all quantities on line items for all products related to opportunities in the trigger set. The second query looks only at the product and all line items associated with that product, regardless of whether they were line items related to opportunities in the original trigger set.

Comment: Guys, lets me explain my problem better... Ok, we have a Product and I have 100 in stock. Then I have an order for 20 Closed Won so now when I go to my Product screen the Qty on Hand have to say 80.

Comment: That's the solution I've given you, the way to keep track of how many you've used up at any given time, which can always be recalculated based on actual data not the subtraction of quantity from one transaction to the next.

Comment: @greenstork though you are using a field that you assume exists. And with your solution it would require a formula field to actually determine what is left on hand. Also, there is the potential that your aggregate may touch more rows than allowed by the governor.

Comment: You can always do the math in apex, although it would require an additional SOQL. If the aggregate touches more rows than 50K, then a batch is needed.

Comment: Your code will not clear out the Quantity Consumed field to 0 if it used to be >0 and then an Opportunity Product was changed or Opp made Closed Lost or something. Although that's a narrow case, I would want to set the Product Quantity Consumed to 0 by default, then fill it in with the aggregate data.

Answer (score -1):

**Basic idea**

There are two problems to solve: (1) Update products if an opportunity is in a specific stage. (2) Reduce the number of SOQL statements and make the solution scalable.

**Solution**

(1) All opportunities are relevant if the old or new value (before or after the update) is "closed won". Therefore only these opportunities will be processed. If stage is updated from "closed won" the quantity of a given opportunity line item (OLI) should be added to QtyOnHand__c. And vice versa.

(2) To implement (1) only one SOQL query is needed.

**Code - Outline**

```
trigger onOpportunity on Opportunity (after update)
{
    Set<Id> relevantIds = new Set<Id>();
    // select relevant opps
    for(Opportunity o : trigger.new)
    {
        if(o.StageName == 'Closed Won' || trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).StageName == 'Closed Won')
        {
            relevantIds.add(o.Id);
        }
    }

    // query Line Items
    Map<Id, Product2> products = new Map<Id, Product2>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : [SELECT ID, PricebookEntry.Product2.Id, PricebookEntry.Product2.QtyOnHand__c, Quantity, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :relevantIds])
    {
        // cache product
        if(!products.containsKey(oli.PricebookEntry.Product2.Id))
        {
            products.put(oli.PricebookEntry.Product2.Id, new Product2(Id = oli.PricebookEntry.Product2.Id, QtyOnHand__c = oli.PricebookEntry.Product2.QtyOnHand__c));
        }
        // get product
        Product2 theProduct = products.get(oli.PricebookEntry.Product2.Id);

        // add on hand if opp was canceled
        if(trigger.oldMap.get(oli.OpportunityId).StageName == 'Closed Won')
        {
            theProduct.QtyOnHand__c += oli.Quantity;
        }
        // add on hand if opp is closed won
        if(trigger.newMap.get(oli.OpportunityId).StageName == 'Closed Won')
        {
            theProduct.QtyOnHand__c -= oli.Quantity;
        }
    }

    if(products.size() > 0)
    {
        update products.values();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Christian I'm getting this error...

> Apex trigger onOpportunity caused an unexpected exception, contact
>   your administrator: onOpportunity: execution of AfterUpdate caused by:
>   System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without
>   querying the requested field: OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId:
>   Trigger.onOpportunity: line 26, column 1

Code:

```
trigger onOpportunity on Opportunity (after update)
{
    Set<Id> relevantIds = new Set<Id>();
    // select relevant opps
    for(Opportunity o : trigger.new)
    {
        if(o.StageName == 'Closed Won' || trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).StageName == 'Closed Won')
        {
            relevantIds.add(o.Id);
        }
    }

    // query Line Items
    Map<Id, Product2> products = new Map<Id, Product2>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : [SELECT ID, PricebookEntry.Product2.Id, PricebookEntry.Product2.QtyOnHand__c, Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :relevantIds])
    {
        // cache product
        if(!products.containsKey(oli.PricebookEntry.Product2.Id))
        {
            products.put(oli.PricebookEntry.Product2.Id, new Product2(Id = oli.PricebookEntry.Product2.Id, QtyOnHand__c = oli.PricebookEntry.Product2.QtyOnHand__c));
        }
        // get product
        Product2 theProduct = products.get(oli.PricebookEntry.Product2.Id);

        // add on hand if opp was canceled
        if(trigger.oldMap.get(oli.OpportunityId).StageName == 'Closed Lost')
        {
            theProduct.QtyOnHand__c += oli.Quantity;
        }
        // add on hand if opp is closed won
        if(trigger.newMap.get(oli.OpportunityId).StageName == 'Closed Won')
        {
            theProduct.QtyOnHand__c -= oli.Quantity;
        }
    }

    if(products.size() > 0)
    {
        update products.values();
    }
}
```

line 26, column 1:

```
if(trigger.oldMap.get(oli.OpportunityId).StageName == 'Closed Lost')
```

Comment: Read the error. It tells you exactly what the issue is, where the problem is, and you can then quickly infer what the solution is.

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh if I knew how fix this kind of error. I wouldn't asking for help...